# Quickbooks QBXML - how to exclude fields

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I want to get all inventory items from quickbooks with only full name and quantity on hand fields, in order to get a smaller xml. Do you know how to achieve this?

This is the xml query request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <ItemInventoryQueryRq>
        </ItemInventoryQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this tag to pick specifically which fields you want to include:

`<IncludeRetElement>`

For example, this gets invoices, but only the `TxnID`, `EditSequence`, and `RefNumber` fields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="abcd1234">

      <TxnID>ABCD-1234</TxnID>

      <IncludeRetElement>TxnID</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>EditSequence</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>RefNumber</IncludeRetElement>

    </InvoiceQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Example from this wiki:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Querying_for_Invoices,_and_limiting_returned_info
- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

You may also want to reference Intuit's documentation which shows this, the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html